# UITapGestureRecognizer timeout?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

If I set numberOfTapsRequired to 2 on a UITapGestureRecognizer, then the user has a certain amount of time after his first tap to tap again to trigger my recognizer.  Does anyone know how to find out the exact amount of time allowed?

By analogy, in Cocoa, NSEvent has the doubleClickInterval class method.  I'm looking for an equivalent in iOS for UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: Doesn't look like it's settable, you could always role your own with an `NSTimer`

Comment: I don't want to set it, I just want to find out what it is.  I need to replicate double tapping without UITapGestureRecognizer, and I want the user to have the same experience as if I were using UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Just guestimate it will most likely be around 0.2f;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the answer is: 0.35 seconds, at least as of today on iOS 5.1.

I created a test application that used a pair of tap recognizers to recognize both single and double taps to update a pair of UIlabels.  I then used [Instruments UI automation](http://guerratopia.com/en/introduction-to-automating-ui-testing-in-ios) to repeatedly send double taps with progressively more time between the taps.  At 0.34 seconds, a series of taps is recognized as a double tap, but at 0.35 seconds, they're recognized as single taps.

This is very much like Lou's suggestion, but different in that I needed to use Instruments.  I could find no way to simulate a user tap within UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

In a test app, create a UITapGestureRecognizer and then start calling the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and associated members on a timer.  See if that causes the gesture to be recognized.

You might have to experiment to figure out how to call it correctly so that any gesture recognizes, but from what I understand, a recognizer just depends on these being called by using them as selectors on a view's versions of the same messages, so calling them yourself should have the same effect.

When you find the number to whatever tolerance you need, you can use that in your app.

Also, since this can change at any time (because Apple just feels like it) -- or it could be different on different iOS versions, you could always incorporate this into your initialization.

Or, you could just get close enough as @Paul suggested in his comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Lou.  I tried your suggestion, but since I can't find a way to create either UITouch or UIEvent objects, I'm only passing nil for those parameters, and the simulated taps are ignored.  But your suggestion got me thinking, and I ended up using the automation tool in Instruments to do basically what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can view UITapGestureRecognizer in debugger and see private variable _maximumIntervalBetweenSuccessiveTaps which is equal to 0.34(9).

[screen from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irATU.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).